# Clean and fast MiniMax for numpy implementation of Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, numpy

Tic-tac-toe is small enough to be solved completely but since I have a slow computer and this is an interesting exercise, I want to build the fastest possible minimax tic-tac-toe implementation in CPython.

I welcome any comments on style, performance and cleaning up code. Here are some points I'm particularly unsure about:

**TicTacToe**

- I currently have functions to undo (`TicTacToe.unmark()`) and do (`TicTacToe.mark()`) a move. I worry, that this is unneeded repetition.
- I use the '@property' decorator when a method is more like a fundamental property of the game then an action taken. Am I using the decorator correctly?

**MiniMax**

- Should I separate out code storing symmetric boards into a new method for readability?
- What can I do about my `MiniMax.best_move()` method. While it is short, I feel it could be more readable.

**Code**

tictactoe.py

```
import numpy as np


class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self, board=None):
        if board is None:
            self.board = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=np.int8)
        elif self._check_board_valid(board):
            self.board = board.astype(dtype=np.int8)

    def mark(self, pos, inplace=True):
        if self.winner is None:
            if pos in self.zero_positions:
                if inplace:
                    self.board[pos] = self.player
                else:
                    b = self.board.copy()
                    b[pos] = self.player

                    return TicTacToe(board=b)
            elif 0 > pos[0] or pos[0] >= 3 or 0 > pos[1] or pos[1] >= 3:
                raise IndexError(f"{pos} is outside board")
            else:
                raise IndexError(f"board marked at {pos} already")

    def un_mark(self, pos, inplace=True):
        if pos in self.possible_undos:
            if inplace:
                self.board[pos] = 0
            else:
                b = self.board.copy()
                b[pos] = 0

                return TicTacToe(board=b)
        elif 0 > pos[0] or pos[0] >= 3 or 0 > pos[1] or pos[1] >= 3:
            raise IndexError(f"{pos} is outside board")
        else:
            raise IndexError(f"Player {-1 * self.player} cannot un-mark board at {pos}")

    @property
    def winner(self):
        """Returns winner of game
        1 : Player 1 has won
        -1 : PLayer 2 has won
        0 : Draw
        None: No winner yet"""

        # check rows
        if any(abs(self.board.sum(axis=1)) == 3):
            s = self.board.sum(axis=1)
            return s[abs(s) == 3][0] // 3

        # check columns
        if any(abs(self.board.sum(axis=0)) == 3):
            s = self.board.sum(axis=0)
            return s[abs(s) == 3][0] // 3

        # check diagonal 0
        elif abs(np.diag(self.board).sum()) == 3:
            return np.diag(self.board).sum() // 3

        # check other diagonal
        elif abs(np.diag(np.fliplr(self.board)).sum()) == 3:
            return np.diag(np.fliplr(self.board)).sum() // 3

        # draw if all positions filled but still no winner
        elif not (self.board == 0).any():
            return 0

        # None is returned automatically if no other condition has been met

    @property
    def zero_positions(self):
        return tuple(zip(*np.where(self.board == 0)))

    @property
    def possible_undos(self):
        return tuple(zip(*np.where(self.board == -1 * self.player)))

    @property
    def player(self):
        try:
            sum_turn_dict = {
                0: 1,
                1: -1
            }
            return sum_turn_dict[self.board.sum()]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid board: cannot determine whose turn it is")

    @staticmethod
    def _check_board_valid(board):
        if type(board) is np.ndarray:
            if board.shape == (3, 3):
                if np.logical_or(abs(board) == 1, board == 0).all():
                    if board.sum() in [0, 1]:
                        return True
                    else:
                        raise ValueError("Invalid board: cannot determine whose turn it is")
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Board must contain only 1, -1 and 0")
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Board must have shape (3, 3), not {board.shape}")
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Board must be ndarray, not {type(board)}")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.board.__repr__()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.board)
```

minimax.py

```
from TicTacToe.tictactoe import TicTacToe
import numpy as np


class MiniMax:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rate_dict = {}
        self.optimal = {
            1: max,
            -1: min
        }
        self.positions_evaluated = 0

    def rate(self, game):
        if str(game) in self.rate_dict:
            value = self.rate_dict[str(game)]
        elif game.winner is not None:
            value = game.winner
        else:
            value = -1 * game.player
            for pos in game.zero_positions:
                game.mark(pos)
                r = self.rate(game=game)
                game.un_mark(pos)

                value = self.optimal[game.player](value, r)

                if value == game.player:
                    break

        self.rate_dict[str(game)] = value

        # Use symmetry (flip and three rotations)
        self.rate_dict[str(np.rot90(game.board, k=1))] = value
        self.rate_dict[str(np.rot90(game.board, k=2))] = value
        self.rate_dict[str(np.rot90(game.board, k=3))] = value

        flipped_board = game.board.T
        self.rate_dict[str(flipped_board)] = value
        self.rate_dict[str(np.rot90(flipped_board, k=1))] = value
        self.rate_dict[str(np.rot90(flipped_board, k=2))] = value
        self.rate_dict[str(np.rot90(flipped_board, k=3))] = value

        self.positions_evaluated += 1
        return value

    def best_move(self, board):
        game = TicTacToe(board)
        pos_list = ((pos, self.rate(game.mark(pos, inplace=False))) for pos in game.zero_positions)
        return self.optimal[game.player](pos_list, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]
```